# Trying to make dots orbit bigger dot

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So I've been attempting to make some dots not only come towards a circle but also to make them orbit it. To do this I am using cosine and sine, however I'm running into issues with getting the dots to move forward as well as setting their distance. With the code below the dots are able to form a circle around the bigger dot, as well as follow it, but they don't approach the dot nor do they, when having the coordinates scaled by their distance from t1, come to that location, but instead do funky stuff. This is referring specifically to the line

```
t2.goto(2 * (t1.xcor() + math.degrees(math.cos(math.radians(t1.towards(t2)))) // 1), 2 * (t1.ycor() + math.degrees(math.sin(math.radians(t1.towards(t2)))) // 1))
```

which I had replaced with:

```
t2.goto(dist * (t1.xcor() + math.degrees(math.cos(math.radians(t1.towards(t2)))) // 1), dist * (t1.ycor() + math.degrees(math.sin(math.radians(t1.towards(t2)))) // 1))
```

and that gave me the sporadic view of the dots attempting to follow the bigger dot.

This line is found in the follow() function. Create() makes the smaller dots, move() moves the bigger dot and grow() grows the bigger dot on collision with the smaller dots. Produce() and redraw() are supposed to be a stage 2 of the program, but those functions are irrelevant to the question. Finally, quit() just exits the Screen() and quits the program.

Thanks to cdlane for help with organizing data and updating the screen more efficiently.

Code as of now:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import sys
import math

CURSOR_SIZE = 20


def move(x, y):
    """ has it follow cursor """

    t1.ondrag(None)

    t1.goto(x, y)

    screen.update()

    t1.ondrag(move)

def grow():
    """ grows t1 shape """

    global t1_size, g

    t1_size += 0.1
    t1.shapesize(t1_size / CURSOR_SIZE)
    g -= .1
    t1.color((r/255, g/255, b/255))

    screen.update()

def follow():
    """ has create()'d dots follow t1 """

    global circles, dist

    new_circles = []

    for (x, y), stamp in circles:

        t2.clearstamp(stamp)

        t2.goto(x, y)

        dist = t2.distance(t1) / 57.29577951308232 // 1
        t2.goto(2 * (t1.xcor() + math.degrees(math.cos(math.radians(t1.towards(t2)))) // 1), 2 * (t1.ycor() + math.degrees(math.sin(math.radians(t1.towards(t2)))) // 1))

        t2.setheading(t2.towards(t1))

        if t2.distance(t1) < t1_size // 1:
            if t2.distance(t1) > t1_size * 1.2:
                t2.forward(500/t2.distance(t1)//1)
            else:
                t2.forward(3)





        if t2.distance(t1) > t1_size // 2:
            new_circles.append((t2.position(), t2.stamp())) 
        else:
            grow()  # we ate one, make t1 fatter

    screen.update()

    circles = new_circles

    if circles:
        screen.ontimer(follow, 10)
    else:
        phase = 1
        produce()

def create():
    """ create()'s dots with t2 """

    count = 0
    nux, nuy = -400, 300

    while nuy > -400:
        t2.goto(nux, nuy)

        if t2.distance(t1) > t1_size // 2:
            circles.append((t2.position(), t2.stamp()))

        nux += 20
        count += 1
        if count == 40:
            nuy -= 50
            nux = -400
            count = 0

    screen.update()

def quit():
    screen.bye()
    sys.exit(0)

def redraw():
    t2.color("black")
    t2.shapesize((t2_size + 4) / CURSOR_SIZE)
    t2.stamp()
    t2.shapesize((t2_size + 2) / CURSOR_SIZE)
    t2.color("white")
    t2.stamp()

def produce():
    #create boundary of star
    global t2_size, ironmax
    t1.ondrag(None)
    t1.ht()
    t2.goto(t1.xcor(), t1.ycor())
    t2.color("black")
    t2.shapesize((t1_size + 4) / CURSOR_SIZE)
    t2.stamp()
    t2.shapesize((t1_size + 2) / CURSOR_SIZE)
    t2.color("white")
    t2.stamp()
    #start producing helium
    while t2_size < t1_size:

        t2.color("#ffff00")
        t2.shapesize(t2_size / 20)
        t2.stamp()
        t2_size += .1
        redraw()
        screen.update()
        ironmax = t2_size
        t2_size = 4
    while t2_size < ironmax:
        t2.shapesize(t2_size / 20)
        t2.color("grey")
        t2.stamp()
        t2_size += .1
        screen.update()


# variables
t1_size = 6
circles = []
phase = 0


screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(900, 900)
#screen.mode("standard")


t2 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
t2.shapesize(4 / CURSOR_SIZE)
t2.speed('fastest')
t2.color('purple')
t2.penup()
t2_size = 4

t1 = Turtle('circle')
t1.shapesize(t1_size / CURSOR_SIZE)
t1.speed('fastest')
r = 190
g = 100
b = 190
t1.color((r/255, g/255, b/255))
t1.penup()

t1.ondrag(move)

screen.tracer(False)

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(quit, "Escape")

create()

follow()
#print(phase)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took another crack at this, just looking at the problem of meteors swarming around a planet.  Or in this case, moon as I chose Deimos as my model.  I attempted to work at scale making the coordinate system 1 pixel = 1 kilometer.  At the start, Deimos sits in a field of meteors each of which has a random heading but they all have the same size and velocity:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import random

METEOR_VELOCITY = 0.011  # kilometers per second

METEOR_RADIUS = 0.5  # kilometers

SECONDS_PER_FRAME = 1000  # each updates represents this many seconds passed

UPDATES_PER_SECOND = 100

DEIMOS_RADIUS = 6.2  # kilometers

G = 0.000003  # Deimos gravitational constant in kilometers per second squared

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def follow():

    global meteors

    new_meteors = []

    t = SECONDS_PER_FRAME

    for (x, y), velocity, heading, stamp in meteors:

        meteor.clearstamp(stamp)
        meteor.goto(x, y)
        meteor.setheading(heading)
        meteor.forward(velocity * t)

        meteor.setheading(meteor.towards(deimos))
        meteor.forward(G * t * t)

        meteor.setheading(180 + meteor.towards(x, y))

        if meteor.distance(deimos) > DEIMOS_RADIUS * 2:
            new_meteors.append((meteor.position(), velocity, meteor.heading(), meteor.stamp()))

    screen.update()

    meteors = new_meteors
    if meteors:
        screen.ontimer(follow, 1000 // UPDATES_PER_SECOND)

def create():
    """ create()'s dots with meteor """

    count = 0
    nux, nuy = -400, 300

    while nuy > -400:
        meteor.goto(nux, nuy)

        if meteor.distance(deimos) > DEIMOS_RADIUS * 2:
            heading = random() * 360
            meteor.setheading(heading)  # all meteors have random heading but fixed velocity
            meteors.append((meteor.position(), METEOR_VELOCITY, meteor.heading(), meteor.stamp()))

        nux += 20
        count += 1
        if count % 40 == 0:
            nuy -= 50
            nux = -400

    screen.update()

meteors = []

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(1000, 1000)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-500, -500, 499, 499)  # 1 pixel = 1 kilometer

meteor = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
meteor.shapesize(2 * METEOR_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
meteor.speed('fastest')
meteor.color('purple')
meteor.penup()

deimos = Turtle('circle')
deimos.shapesize(2 * DEIMOS_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
deimos.color("orange")
deimos.penup()

screen.tracer(False)

create()
follow()

screen.mainloop()
```

The first variable to investigate is `METEOR_VELOCITY`.  At the setting provided, most meteors will crash into the moon but a few obtain orbital velocity.  If you *halve* its value, all meteors will crash into the moon.  If you *double* its value, a few meteors obtain escape velocity, leaving the window; a few may crash into the moon; most will form an orbiting cloud that gets smaller and tighter.

I tossed the trigonometric stuff and reverted back to degrees instead of radians.  I use vector addition logic to work out the motion.

In the end, it's just a crude model.

Answer (score 1):

By changing 180 to some other offsets, for example 195, in the `def follow()` in [cdlane's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50673179/5171605) code,

```
meteor.setheading(195 + meteor.towards(x, y))
```

then the metors would not go straight (180 degree) towards the Deimos, but instead would show some spiral movement towards the center.

Great example provided!